# How can I union the documents of two (or more) mongoDB collections, into the results of a query?

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections that I would like to keep separate in the DB, but I would like to union the two into the results of a query.

capitals:

```
{ 
    "name" : "Austin",       
    "latitude" : "11111", 
    "longitude" : "22222"
    "extra_information" : {
        "best_pizza" : "xxxxx", 
        "mayor" : "John Smith"
    }
}
{ 
    "name" : "Albany",         
    "latitude" : "33333", 
    "longitude" : "44444"
    "extra_information" : {
        "best_pizza" : "xxxxx", 
        "mayor" : "John Doe"
    }
}
```

non_capitals:

```
{ 
    "name" : "Beaumont",       
    "latitude" : "55555", 
    "longitude" : "66666"
}
{ 
    "name" : "Syracuse",       
    "latitude" : "77777", 
    "longitude" : "88888"
}
```

I would like my query to return:

```
{ 
    "name" : "Austin",       
    "latitude" : "11111", 
    "longitude" : "22222"
    "extra_information" : {
        "best_pizza" : "xxxxx", 
        "mayor" : "John Smith"
    }
}
{ 
    "name" : "Albany",         
    "latitude" : "33333", 
    "longitude" : "44444"
    "extra_information" : {
        "best_pizza" : "xxxxx", 
        "mayor" : "John Doe"
    }
}
{ 
    "name" : "Beaumont",       
    "latitude" : "55555", 
    "longitude" : "66666"
}
{ 
    "name" : "Syracuse",       
    "latitude" : "77777", 
    "longitude" : "88888"
}
```

I have found solutions for when the second collection should be keyed to a field in the first using $lookup, but nothing for a simple SQL UNION-style operation. For example, I don't care to match the non-capitals with the state of each capitol.

To be clear: I am trying to create a query to return the results of appending the second (and third, and nth) collection to first, without modifying either. I don't want to create a third collection, either, only return results.

An answer as MongoShell would be as good as a raw query.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23475006/perform-union-in-mongodb) may help. It's a non-relational database so I would first suggest instead of having two separate `capital` and `non-capital` to have just single collection with extra field, e.g. `isCapital` which will hold boolean value. It's better here, in case of NoSQL DB, to store info in non-related collections. If some of collections are somehow related, better go with SQL (e.g. PostgreSQL or SQLite).

Comment: It is a requirement to keep the collections separate. I have obviously doctored these documents for clarity, but here is the constraint: the `capitals` collection will have very few documents, but with thousands of `extra_information` fields, and will be accessed extremely frequently. The `non-captials` collection will only contain `name`, `lat`, and `long`, but will contain millions of documents and be accessed very infrequently. It seems keeping the non-captials in the same collection will eventually 'clog up' the frequent queries where I really only need info about capitals.